# Update operation adds in a new array instead of adding array elements

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

My controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}/giveFacilitiesAccess", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public Object giveFacilityAccessToAnotherUser(@PathVariable("id") String userId)
    {
        return userService.giveFacilitiesAccessToAnotherUser(userId);
    }
```

My service:

```
@Override
    public Object giveFacilitiesAccessToAnotherUser(String id)
    {
        String userId = getLoggedInUserId();
        User u = userDao.findById(userId);
        List<String> facilitiesAccess = u.getFacilitiesAccess();
        return userDao.giveFacilitiesAccessToAnotherUser(id,facilitiesAccess);

    }
```

My dao:

```
@Override
    public Object giveFacilitiesAccessToAnotherUser(String userId, List<String>facilitiesAccess)
    {
        Query query = new Query();
        query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("id").is(userId));
        Update update = new Update().addToSet("facilitiesAccess.",facilitiesAccess);
        mongoTemplate.updateFirst(query, update, User.class);
        return null;
    }
```

After updating:
"facilitiesAccess":["5f0996f792691d1b68671da3",["5f0998ba92691d1b68671da4"]]

```
It's updating like array inside another array, but i need in this format:
"facilitiesAccess":["5f0996f792691d1b68671da3","5f0998ba92691d1b68671da4"]
```

Answer (score 1):

The update works with the syntax using the `addToSet(String key)` which returns a `Update.AddToSetBuilder` - then apply the `each(Object... values)` method on the builder, to return the `Update` object.

```
Update update = new Update().addToSet("facilitiesAccess").each(facilitiesAccess);
```

Comment: Thnaks now it is adding in array

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Each like below

```
    @Override
    public Object giveFacilitiesAccessToAnotherUser(String userId, List<String>facilitiesAccess)
    {
        Query query = new Query();
        query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("id").is(userId));
        Update update = new Update().addToSet("facilitiesAccess.",new Each(facilitiesAccess));
        mongoTemplate.updateFirst(query, update, User.class);
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: no, its still showing an error.  not working suggest me any another